# Calculating diagonal scale?

Tags: scale

How to Calculate a diagonal scale to read 1.4375 mile when the given R.F. is 1:25344 and 1 inch is divided into 32 tertiary division ?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to achieve. Are you looking for the scale element size? Why does the inch division matter?

Comment: What is a "diagonal scale"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but:

If 1/scale = 25344 and since 36 inch = 1 yard and 1760 yard = 1 mile, then
1 inch (map) represents 25344 inch (ground) = 704.00 yard = 0.4000 mile
and
1.4375 mile = 2530.0 yard = 91,080 inch (ground) represented by 3.59375 inch (map)
Finally,
3.59375 inch = 3 and 19/32 inch